# Map of types in Golang?

Tags: dictionary, go, types

I am writing a parser for audio/video stream which is known to be comprised of frames of several certain types. Each frame type has its own subheader format, so I define a struct type for each to use them for variables passed as the 3rd argument to [binary.Read](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Read):

```go
type TypeVideoIHeader struct {
    MType       byte // type of media e.g. H.264
    FPS         byte
    Width       byte
    Height      byte
    DateTime    int32
    Length      int32
}

type TypeVideoPHeader struct {
    Length      int32
}

type TypeAudioHeader struct {
    MType       byte
    SampleRate  byte
    Length      int16
}
```

Which type a frame is is defined by a certain byte in its header, so I put those into constants:

```go
type FrameType byte

const (
    VideoI  FrameType = 0xFC
    VideoP  FrameType = 0xFD
    Audio   FrameType = 0xFA
)
```

Now, before I can call `binary.Read` **I have to create a variable of the right type** (one of the 3 structs above) which the function will fill with values from the stream.

How do I initialise a variable of the right type just by a `FrameType` variable? Is there a concise and elegant solution?

Say if this kind of trick was possible:

```go
TMap := map[FrameType]type{
    VideoI: TypeVideoIHeader,
    VideoP: TypeVideoPHeader,
    Audio: TypeAudioHeader,
}

var videoISubHeader TMap[VideoI]
```

— that would be sort of what I am after.

Comment: What you need is [_polymorphism_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)); interfaces (and soon, generics) enable polymorphism in Go. Simply declare an interface type that all three of your struct types satisfy; then use that interface type as your map's value type.

Comment: @jub0bs It looks like interfaces define the functional contract, but the structs in my example have no functions.

Comment: Then you can use the empty interface (`interface{}`) or give yourself a so-called [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern).

Answer (score 7):

```golang
TMap := map[FrameType]func() interface{} {
    VideoI: func() interface{} { return &TypeVideoIHeader{} },
    VideoP: func() interface{} { return &TypeVideoPHeader{} },
    Audio:  func() interface{} { return &TypeAudioHeader{} },
}

var videoISubHeader = TMap[VideoI]()

if err := binary.Read(r, order, videoISubHeader); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Note that `binary.Read` expects the 3rd argument to be a pointer, else it won't be able to read the binary data into the passed in variable, which is why the functions use `&`.

Comment: After the read operation, `videoISubHeader` remains an `interface{}`. How to access the property `Length`, common for all the 3 struct types? Guess by using type assertion. So we are back where we started from: how to assert the right type by `VideoI`?

Comment: @Greendrake Type assertion or, you can declare an interface type with getter methods, implement those methods on all of your header types, and then in the `TMap` definition replace the `interface{}` type with the new non-empty interface type.

Comment: @Greendrake note that what you were hoping for is not possible with Go, at least not at the moment, maybe sometime in 2022 when generics are scheduled to be added you'll be able to get closer to your goal, but at the moment you'll have to be content with interfaces.

Comment: @Greendrake one more thing, if you have no intent in creating an interface type, then you can use reflection to access [struct fields by name](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.FieldByName). Reflection is usually discouraged but if that's what you need then that's what you should use.